# Prove that the following argument is invalid

Tags: modal-logic

$□p$, $□q$
therefore, $□(p→q)$

according to the K system of modal logic, the argument is invalid. I tried proving it using a truth tree, but all the branches unfortunately close, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Your math is not displaying right, so it might be a good idea to format it using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I am not sure whether the display is showing correctly (as mentioned above), but I think the argument you mention might be valid. Could you confirm whether it is $\vdash []p$ and $\vdash []q$ then $\vdash [](p\rightarrow q)$?

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that $\Box(p \rightarrow q)$ is not a logical consequence of $\{\Box p, \Box q\}$ in $K$ is ambiguous. It can be read as saying that $\Box(p \rightarrow q)$ is a not local consequence of $\{\Box p, \Box q\}$ and as saying that the formula is not a global consequence of the formula set. For present purposes, local consequence can be defined as preservation of satisfaction at every point from every $K$-model; global consequence means preservation of validity on every $K$-frame.

However, your claim is wrong under both of its interpretations. To see that the formula $\Box(p \rightarrow q)$ is a local consequence, note that it  is a local consequence of $\Box q$ and that local consequence is monotonic. Analogous reasoning shows that the formula is a global consequence.